# When can a new user up-vote?

Tags: support, status-completed

The OP of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99581/data-format-for-checking-a-land-survey-deed) told me privately he couldn't up-vote my answer because he had insufficient points. The site wouldn't let him.

When would he?

Comment: Awarded at: 15 reputation http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: @Mapperz: Aha, thanks. And rep required for Accepting and answer? I didn't see that listed. (If not, it seems odd that newcomers cannot accept answers to their own questions.)

Answer (score 5):

At the **[Help Center > Privileges](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)** page it says, amongst many other things:

> 15 - vote up - Indicate when questions and answers are useful

and

> 1 - create posts - Ask a question or contribute an answer

Although not explicitly stated, my understanding is that as soon as you have the privilege to ask a Question, you also have the privilege to Accept an Answer to it.